# I downloaded NodeJS from the official website but it doesn't work Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

On the official NodeJS website I downloaded the recommended [windows installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). I tried on Ubuntu to see my version, node -v, and it doesn't work. When I type anything with node it says:

```
command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nodejs
```

I tried sudo apt install nodejs and I got another error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
```

Trying npm is not any better

```
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 3:
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 5:
/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: 6: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

However, when I search node on the windows task bar, there is a node app that is listed and it opens a terminal. I'm new to Linux and it's my first time using Ubuntu, and I'm on windows 10, please advise me on what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, 'sudo apt update', then 'sudo apt install nodejs' -- no space between node and js

If that doesn't work:

## Using Ubuntu

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

## Try this

sudo apt install curl
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash

then

nvm install stable

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It didn't work, it says this: /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Did the curl command work (Did it download a file)? Are you logged in as root already? Just run 'sudo apt-get install nodejs' again

Comment: I tried it again and it just does what I put on my second example. Ending with E: Unable to locate package nodejs. Thanks.

Comment: The first two steps worked! But the last line, nvm install stable didn't. It says: /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file.

Comment: Try to not use sudo, or just log in as root and try that: 'su root'

Comment: My bad. It actually said: "Command 'nvm' not found, did you mean: a list of stuff". I went onto root and tried it again and it says the same thing.

Comment: As root, do: apt install curl, then 'curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash', then, 'nvm install stable'

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately it did the same thing, the first two worked but the last didn't. Maybe I could do some sort of hard reset? Deleting all of linux/Ubuntu and Node and reinstalling it again, or something like that? I don't know how this works.

Comment: just type 'bash' and hit enter. that will spawn a new shell. then try 'nvm install stable'

Comment: Well, would you believe that. I closed the terminal. Opened it again from windows, typed 'npm install stable' and somehow, it worked!! So simple, but wouldn't work all this time. Amazing! Thank you Jordan, from the UK.

Comment: Glad I could help!